# What is the structure of DNA polymerase III?

Tags: molecular-biology, literature

According to Snustard and Simmons the structure of DNA polymerase III is the following, where the clamp loader( γ -δ complex ) is present on one side:
[image]

But according to Lehninger the clamp loader is centrally located:
[image]

Which one is right? Besides where can I find a correct diagrammatic representation of DNA polymerase III?

---

I recently found [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3290774/) paper which supports the second mentioned structure of DNA pol III.

Comment: I don't know the answer myself, but if you have access to Nature Structural Biology I would start with this recent paper and work back from it if necessary. (I found it by searching the Protein Data Bank (PDB) for E.coli DNA pol III): http://www.nature.com/nsmb/journal/v24/n2/pdf/nsmb.3348.pdf .

Comment: It's a problem then.You might try looking at the visualizations available in the various PDB entries, but it would probably be much more work than is justified. Hope there's someone on the list that works in the field and can tell you or reproduce an appropriate figure.